# Gson Deserialize Json with extends class java

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

i have a json file and  try to read serialized values,
i have created a custom Deserialize for getting extended classes here is my custom Derserialize;

```
switch (type.getAsString()) {
                case "ToLowerRule":
                    return context.deserialize(jsonObject, 
                        ToLowerRule.class);
                case "ParserDataRule":
                    return context.deserialize(jsonObject, 
                            ParserDataRule.class);
                case "CityRule":
                    return context.deserialize(jsonObject, 
                            CityRule.class);
```

and  my classes;

```
public class ToLowerRule extends BasicRule {...}
public class ParserDataRule extends BasicRule {...}
public class CityRule extends ParserDataRule {...}
```

and Gson object;

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(BasicRule.class, 
                              new CustomRuleDeserializer()).create();
```

its Deserialize the ToLowerRule and ParseDataRule but its Deserialize CityRule as ParserDataRule can some one help me out about this .

I want CityRule to Deserialize as CityRule not as extended object (ParseDataRule)

Thank you.

Comment: In type.getAsString(), is *type* java.lang.reflect.Type or a member object of BasicRule?

Comment: Its a field where class names stored. So its member of basicrule

Comment: I tried something similar on my side and it's working fine. Could you double check if your CityRule::type.getAsString() is working properly?

Comment: its setting value but problem is when i add those fields to in necessary arraylist and  create new objects from city its not creating even not going to city class

Comment: Could you put your code for creating cities list here?

Comment: Thank you i handled  it with another way. I used two custom de serilalizer   i just  can't do downcasting after  create  object with super class